# Prove whether a 4x4 matrix with three eigenvalues is diagonalizable (Without given matrix).

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

A is a 4x4 matrix with three eigenvalues. One eigenspace is one-dimensional, and one of the other eigenspaces is two-dimensional. Is it possible that A is not diagonalizable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A matrix is diagonalizable iff there is a basis of eigenvectors for the vector space in which we are - or equivalently: if there is an invertible matrix $S$ such that $SAS^{-1}$ is a diagonal matrix.

Now we know that eigenvectors of distinct eigenvalues are linearly independet and therefore the union of all eigenvectors is a linearly independent system. If we have one eigenspace being two-dimensional and the other two eigenspaces one-dimensional we get a system of four linearly independent eigenvectors - these form a basis because obviously $K^4$ is four-dimensional (where $K$ is the field in which the entries of the matrix lie). So the matrix is diagonalizable. (Or we could say that setting $S$ as the matrix that consists of the four eigenvectors as columns would give us that $SAS^{-1}$ is a diagonal matrix).

Comment: Just to clarify something, if the question was exactly the same except the fact that the 2 eigenspaces are one-dimensional and we do not know anything about the third one, does that mean we cannot know for sure that the A is diagonalizable?

Comment: Yes that is correct.